# In what ways can someone increase their brain function while reading

Tags: learning, reading

On Facebook, someone posed the following question:

> In what ways can someone increase brain function while reading?  I like to read but have problems retaining information.  Sometimes I get a headache that seems to bound off anything I read, and the more I read the more it bounces off.

My answer would be:

> Split your target text into smaller chunks and read each multiple times, so you can build "islands of understanding" before moving on. Do you have an example text you are stuck on?

Are there more methods for improving reading in this fashion?

Related:

[Is it possible to improve reading speed and visual comprehension by doing exercises?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/265/is-it-possible-to-improve-reading-speed-and-visual-comprehension-by-doing-exerci?rq=1)

Comment: I am closing this question because it's been open for many months with no answer and has been attracting close votes. I believe it's not getting answers because it's somewhat vague and unclear. If it can be edited and improved, I will reopen it, but as it currently stands, it's not a good fit for the site.